# Using the Where Statement on a Created Variable

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code that creates the `Checkin_day` variable from `CHECKIN_DATE_TIME`. I'd like to only select 'Sundays' from the newly created `Checkin_day` variable but I'm getting an invalid column name error (because it is not a variable within the dataset). What can I add to my code so that I can select only records that fall on a 'Sunday'? Is this a declare issue or do I need to sub-query?

```
use EMTCQIData

DECLARE @StartDate Date
DECLARE @EndDate Date

Set @StartDate = '01/01/2018'
Set @EndDate = '12/31/2018'

SELECT *, 
Format([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME],'dddd') AS [Checkin_Day]
FROM ED_TAT_MASTER
WHERE (CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate) AND 
Checkin_Day = '*Sunday*'
```

Comment: Just to be sure: `CHECKIN_DATE_TIME` - is a column in `ED_TAT_MASTER`?

Comment: Yes, it is. You are correct!

Comment: It's not clear from your question: `invalid column name error` - which column name is invalid?

Comment: Instead of applying criteria to the new column name, you will have to repeat the formula in the WHERE clause.

Comment: the Checkin_Day column is 'invalid column name error'

Comment: `and datepart(weekday, CHECKIN_DATE_TIME) = 1` This assumes you have `@@datefirst` set as Sunday. Effectively `select` is logically the last part of the query and you can't referenced aliased columns as a `where` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try querying the actual column, not the alias.

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date
DECLARE @EndDate Date

Set @StartDate = '01/01/2018'
Set @EndDate = '12/31/2018'

SELECT *, 
    FORMAT([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME], 'dddd') AS [Checkin_Day]
FROM 
    ED_TAT_MASTER
WHERE 
    (CHECKIN_DATE_TIME > @StartDate and CHECKIN_DATE_TIME < @EndDate) 
    AND FORMAT([CHECKIN_DATE_TIME], 'dddd') = 'Sunday' -- <- here
```

Also you can query by using DATEPART like `DATEPART(dw, [CHECKIN_DATE_TIME]) = 0` 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add an AND to your WHERE clause to only get records that fall on Sunday.

Comment: You should expand on your answer and provide the code to illustrate,

Comment: @nicomp I don't like to do this right away, as it deprives the poster of an opportunity to research and do it themselves, which will help them learn.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman, I've learned a lot from you. I included 'AND Checkin_Day = '*Sunday*' to my WHERE clause and it is resulting in the invalid column name error

Comment: @Greg you can't use `Checkin_Day` in the WHERE clause, you have to use `CHECKIN_DATE_TIME`.   Look into the DATEPART function to see how you can test if it is a Sunday.

Comment: @TabAlleman The point is that your answer may be voted down or closed because it is not complete. What you have posted should actually be in a comment.